# Problems that have bothered me all day. What is the difference between the "type" attribute and the "as" attribute in the <link/> tag?

Tags: javascript, html

Problems that have bothered me all day. What is the difference between the "type" attribute and the "as" attribute in the  tag?
They are all used to specify the type.
What's the difference?

Comment: _as_ ? can you provide an example?

Comment: `as` specifies what it is - eg, `as "font"` and `type` describes the mime-type - eg, `type="font/woff"`

Comment: Have you seen https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/link ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`type` indicates `media_type` whereas `as` indicates a specific class of content.